# How to fix multiple page number and search in datatable? It keep load extra page number and search when i click (refer detail below))

Tags: datatables

[image]

I have table with id "example". 
To insert the input, user need to click Add button.
Popup will appear, user will key in and click insert. This will trigger the jquery code below.
But when, i close the popup and click Add button again to reopen the popup and proceed to key in and insert the data. it start to add extra page number and search.

I try put this after the datatable initialisation, but this will clear all the datatable style. i try to put before the initialisation, but it somehow make my function do not work.

//remove datable style-return to initial html
    var table = $('#example').dataTable().fnDestroy();

```
var networkdeviceItems = [];
var index = 1;     





$("#addValueNetwork").click(function () {

//create object
var networkdeviceItem = {};

//get val from popup input
networkdeviceItem.Number = index;
networkdeviceItem.Hostname_network = document.getElementById("inputhostname_network").value;

networkdeviceItem.Os_network = document.getElementById("inputos_network").value;

networkdeviceItem.Ipaddress_network = document.getElementById("inputipaddress_network").value;

networkdeviceItem.Location_network = document.getElementById("inputlocation_network").value;

networkdeviceItem.Remarks_network = document.getElementById("inputremarks_network").value;

networkdeviceItems.push(networkdeviceItem);

       $('#example').dataTable({
            "destroy": true,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",

            data: networkdeviceItems,
            columns: [
                { title: "No", data: "Number" },
                { title: "Hostname", data: "Hostname_network" },
                { title: "Model", data: "Os_network" },
                { title: "IP", data: "Ipaddress_network" },
                { title: "Location", data: "Location_network" },
                { title: "Remarks", data: "Remarks_network" }
            ]
        });



 index++;

    });
```

I expect the table not to add extra page and search everytime:

1. I exit the popup input
2. Click add to reopen popup input
3. Click insert

It should just continue to add data, continue from the previous insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually added these code to remove the extra element created by datatable. Now it works as expected.

//remove extra info,paginate,length,filter - datatable defect

```
$('#example_info').remove();
$('#example_paginate').remove();    
$('#example_length').remove();
$('#example_filter').remove();
```

---

Updated code as below:

```
   var networkdeviceItems = [];
   var index = 1;     

$("#addValueNetwork").click(function () {

//create object
var networkdeviceItem = {};

//get val from popup input
networkdeviceItem.Number = index;
networkdeviceItem.Hostname_network = document.getElementById("inputhostname_network").value;

networkdeviceItem.Os_network = document.getElementById("inputos_network").value;

networkdeviceItem.Ipaddress_network = document.getElementById("inputipaddress_network").value;

networkdeviceItem.Location_network = document.getElementById("inputlocation_network").value;

networkdeviceItem.Remarks_network = document.getElementById("inputremarks_network").value;

networkdeviceItems.push(networkdeviceItem);

 if (index == 1) {
       $('#example').dataTable({
            "destroy": true,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",

            data: networkdeviceItems,
            columns: [
                { title: "No", data: "Number" },
                { title: "Hostname", data: "Hostname_network" },
                { title: "Model", data: "Os_network" },
                { title: "IP", data: "Ipaddress_network" },
                { title: "Location", data: "Location_network" },
                { title: "Remarks", data: "Remarks_network" }
            ]
        });
}

if (index > 1) {
           //remove extra info,paginate,length,filter - datatable defect
            $('#example_info').remove();
            $('#example_paginate').remove();

            $('#example_length').remove();
            $('#example_filter').remove();

$('#example').dataTable({
            "destroy": true,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",

            data: networkdeviceItems,
            columns: [
                { title: "No", data: "Number" },
                { title: "Hostname", data: "Hostname_network" },
                { title: "Model", data: "Os_network" },
                { title: "IP", data: "Ipaddress_network" },
                { title: "Location", data: "Location_network" },
                { title: "Remarks", data: "Remarks_network" }
            ]
        });

 index++;

    });
```